# Is it possible to edit the data sort in union table?using mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to search and edit the data in 2 tables. I have use union to combine the 2 table. Is it possible to edit the data after sorting by this query?

```
Select * 
from (
    SELECT columnA,columnB,columnC,columnD FROM T1
    union 
    select  columnA,columnB,columnC,columnD from T2) d
WHERE columnB='123'
```

Comment: What do you mean "edit the data"?

Comment: Include a discriminator column or ensure there are keys on each table that are mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean allow the user to update the data, and have it stored in the correct original table? Then do this:

```
SELECT "T1" source, columnA, columnB, columnC, columnD
FROM T1
WHERE columnB = '123'
UNION
SELECT "T2" source, columnA, columnB, columnC, columnD
FROM T2
WHERE columnB = '123'
```

Then when the user is submitting the update, you can use the `source` column to know which table the row originally came from, and update that table.

Comment: Yes, i mean to allow user to update the data and store in the original table.